# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

i got this error :

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pumma2`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_roles_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`roles_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `users` (`username`, `email`, `name`, `password`, `cover`, `roles_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (qweqwe, haikalhikmi@gmail.com, qweqweqew, $2y$10$YX2OPPTGEDcquYkgk.ln6eEuwtFqrtmRbIpvgEZqJJHR9gk8mfdfm, wallpaper-27058.jpg, 1, 2016-12-11 06:09:41, 2016-12-11 06:09:41))

this is my RegisterController

```html
$user=$request->file('cover');
        $destination ='img/user';
        $filename=$user->getClientOriginalName();
        storage::put('img/user/'.$filename,file_get_contents($request->file('cover')->getRealPath()));
 
        $user = new User();
                
        $user->username = $request->username;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->cover = $filename;
        $user->roles_id = DB::table('roles')->select('id')->where('rolename','user')->first()->id;       
                 
        $user->save();
```

when i try dd($user):

it works :

```html
attributes: array:6 [▼
    "username" => "qweqwe"
    "email" => "haikalhikmi@gmail.com"
    "name" => "qweqweqew"
    "password" => "$2y$10$Ci5usZFP6ANCyBfQhN3Gzexh98Wb8R9n4AmVEvq8x/4bakfGF8l/y"
    "cover" => "wallpaper-27058.jpg"
    "roles_id" => 1
  ]
```

just in case if you want to see my user table

```html
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('roles_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('cover');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('rolename');
        });

        schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table){            
            $table->foreign('roles_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code above the Users have belongTo relationship with the Roles. So the migration for the Users foreign key should be as

```
schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table){            
        $table->foreign('roles_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

});
```

The `roles_id` column should reference the `id` column on the `roles` table and not the `users` table.

Changing the foreign key should help you get rid of the constraint violation.

**UPDATE** (More explanation to OP's query in the comment below)

In the RegisterController code in the question

```
$user->roles_id = DB::table('roles')->select('id')->where('rolename','user')->first()->id;
```

throws an exception because `DB::table('roles')->select('id')` - this part will return an integer, chaining from here on `->where('rolename','user')->first()->id` will be like trying to find a property on a plain integer which will result in an exception.

So the query can be defined as

```
$user->roles_id = DB::table('roles')->where('rolename', 'user')->first()->id;

/* 
    Or - to get just the id instead of the entire record 
 */ 

$user->roles_id = DB::table('roles')->where('rolename', 'user')->value('id'); 

/* 
    Or - if there is a Role model defined corresponding to the roles table 
 */

$user->roles_id = \Role::where('rolename', 'user')->first()->id;
```

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object on RegisterController line 48
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
line 48 :
$user->roles_id = DB::table('roles')->select('id')->where('rolename','user')->first()->id;

Comment: Haven't you defined a Role model in your project? The use can use eloquent as $user->roles_id = \Role::where('rolename', 'user')->first()->id; In your query $user->roles_id = DB::table('roles')->select('id') is returning just an integer id, continuing the chaining on id would definitely not work and throw the exception. You could have $user->roles_id = DB::table('roles')->where('rolename', 'user')->first()->id;